# distirbution of Y random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

> When $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ we have $M_{z}(t)= e^{\mu t + (\sigma t)^2/2}$. If we know $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $Y=4X+10$,
>   show that $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(4 \mu + 10, 16 \sigma^2).$

i know that 
$$
M_Y(t)
 = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{tY}\right]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{t(4X+10)}\right]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{4tX} \cdot e^{10t}\right]
$$

but how can i find the distributions?

Comment: I suggest you use capital letters for random variables: $$ M_Y(t) = E[e^{tY}] = E[e^{(4X+10)t}] = E[e^{4Xt}]e^{10t}=M_X(4t)e^{10t}$$

Comment: @Michael thankyou! is this right?

Comment: So then you just show the result has the desired form $e^{mt + (st)^2/2}$. You pick off the $m$ and $s$ values.

Comment: @Michael is it $e^{10t+\frac{(4t)^2}{2}}$?? but i still dont understand, how to compute the mean and variance , and the relation to mgf

Comment: How are you getting $e^{10t + \frac{(4t)^2}{2}}$? The relation to MGF is direct: $M_X(t)$ is an MGF for $X$, where $X$ is Gaussian $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Comment: See here for a detailed answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344859/sum-of-normal-independent-random-variables-with-coefficients